# Asp.net Core JWT SSO Implementation

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, single-sign-on

Good day everyone,

I have a conceptual question regarding the feature in the title. I've been searching around but cannot find any useful information because I am either missing the concept completely or there is an overflow of examples on the internet.

The problem is fairly simple:

We have three web applications. All of these are aspnet core based and use IdentityFramework along with JWT for authentication as well as authorization. Each have their own database. Recently, a request has come up to rip out the JWT token issuing code and place it in a single separate application to be able to implement SSO. All fine and dandy.

But: each application has an extended user object that is app specific, along with claims that are app specific and stored in each individual database. We'd like to keep the basic info on the new login server (email, password, phone number... the standard IdentityUser model), while the extended info would need to come from each individual app. This way (I suspect) we could enable google log on our apps as well.

Could someone kindly either explain to me the core concept of SSO using JWT for multiple apps or at least direct me to a book/extensive article about the subject? I need a starting point.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution or anything usable?

Comment: Not really. We ended up developing a custom solution that in theory works quite well, but crushes some OAuth directives in the process. It covers our case though. If you'd like to know more, start a forum/chat or sth and I'd be glad to elaborate.

Comment: Hey Jason, Good evening! I am in a similar situation, would you please help me out a bit on how to proceed with it? Thanks!

Comment: @Dronacharya To put it simply, the SSO server generates identity jwt tokens after a successful login, be it google, facebook or otherwise (proving you are a logged in user and issuing a unique user id). Each application then provides their own claims and repacks the jwt upon &quot;login&quot; request. The latter is of course done in middleware, not bothering the user.